# Spring retry - can @Recover be in standalone class?

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-retry

I have a Spring Integration app with multiple endpoint that process the same data in different ways.

They all have identical '@Recover' methods which has become boilerplate and seems fragile.

Can you you centralize the @Recover method (e.g. in a standalone class) and/or can you specify how to find this @Recover annotated method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear why would one use a `@Retryable` in Spring Integration when there is that `RequestHandlerRetryAdvice`: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/messaging-endpoints.html#message-handler-advice-chain...

Anyway see this option on the `@Retryable`:

```
/**
 * Retry interceptor bean name to be applied for retryable method. Is mutually
 * exclusive with other attributes.
 * @return the retry interceptor bean name
 */
String interceptor() default "";
```

So, instead of `@Recover` method you provide your own:

```
    @Bean
    public MethodInterceptor retryInterceptor() {
        return RetryInterceptorBuilder.stateless()
                     .maxAttempts(...)
                     .recoverer(...)
                     .build();
    }
  ...
  @Retryable(interceptor = "retryInterceptor")
    public void service() {
```

Comment: Reason I'm not using RequestHandlerRetryAdvice is I couldn't see an annotation/way to integrate without XML -  my MessagingGateway/Gateway and ServiceActivator are simple annotations to avoid bloated XML and Retryable works fine for my use-case (simply network glitches as endpoints integrate with FTP, SharePoint etc. just wanted to centralise recording failures).....  Unless there's another approach you could recommend.  Overall I like that the interceptor is explicit in your answer; means other devs can figure it out even if they're not familiar with Spring Integration.

Comment: See `@ServiceActivator` `adviceChain`. That's where you can configure that `RequestHandlerRetryAdvice`.